# Zabbix getting info about active DB connections from tomcat datasource

Tags: tomcat7, jmx, zabbix

I am trying to configure zabbix to obtain information from tomcat about active jdbc connections from datasource i am add this property in a different ways like:

```
jmx["Catalina:class=javax.sql.DataSource,name='jdbc/someDB',type=DataSource",active]
```

And like:

```
jmx[Catalina:class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="jdbc/someDB",type=DataSource,active]
```

And like:

```
jmx["Catalina:class=javax.sql.DataSource,name=\"jdbc/someDB\",type=DataSource",active]
```

But avery time i get "Not supported" at this item.
Where do i wrong if so?

UPDATE: adding screenshot of property with jmxter
[image: Screenshot of property with jmxterm.]

UPDATE: When i set key as

```
jmx["Catalina:class=javax.sql.DataSource,name=jdbc/someDB,type=DataSource",active]
```

In the zabbix items, than i get in logs this:

```
2014-11-19 05:50:40.136 [pool-1-thread-3] DEBUG com.zabbix.gateway.ItemChecker - getting value for item 'jmx[Catalina:class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="jdbc/someDB",type=DataSource,active]
'
2014-11-19 05:50:40.136 [pool-1-thread-3] DEBUG com.zabbix.gateway.ItemChecker - caught exception for item 'jmx[Catalina:class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="jdbc/someDB",type=DataSource,acti
ve]'
com.zabbix.gateway.ZabbixException: required key format: jmx[<object name>,<attribute name>]
        at com.zabbix.gateway.JMXItemChecker.getStringValue(JMXItemChecker.java:121) [zabbix-java-gateway-2.2.6.jar:na]
        at com.zabbix.gateway.ItemChecker.getJSONValue(ItemChecker.java:88) ~[zabbix-java-gateway-2.2.6.jar:na]
        at com.zabbix.gateway.JMXItemChecker.getValues(JMXItemChecker.java:96) [zabbix-java-gateway-2.2.6.jar:na]
        at com.zabbix.gateway.SocketProcessor.run(SocketProcessor.java:63) [zabbix-java-gateway-2.2.6.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_31]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_31]
```

Comment: If you are using JConsole or VisualVM for accessing these JMX objects, could you please post their screenshot? Meanwhile, you might find http://serverfault.com/questions/582597/zabbix-jmx-jboss-monitoring useful.

Comment: Screenshot added. :)

Comment: Among the keys you listed, the last one looks correct. Could you please show some trace log from Java gateway when this item is queried? Log level can be set to trace in lib/logback.xml file by setting "level" attribute of "root" element to "trace".

Comment: This what i get it logs.

Comment: We originally talked about item `jmx["Catalina:...`, whereas now you posted a log for `jmx["tomcat.jdbc:...`, so it is hard to judge these two separate cases. A quick guess would be to consider changing "Active" to "active" in the item key, because that is how the word is written on the screenshot, although that is a totally different object.

Comment: You right, i change the key to the presented in the begining and update log depends on new value of the key.

Comment: The last log clearly states that the format of the key is wrong: `jmx[Catalina:class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="jdbc/someDB",type=DataSource,active]` - it has four arguments, while it should have only two. It is also different from the third key in your list (which looks correct), which I suggested in one of the comments above. Could you please check that your item is set to `jmx["Catalina:class=javax.sql.DataSource,name=\"jdbc/someDB\",type=DataSource",active]` and post the log message for this item?

Comment: Ok, i will check it ASAP and answer to you. Thank you for support. :)

Comment: Yes, i am sure that my key is:
    jmx["Catalina:class=javax.sql.DataSource,name=\"jdbc/someDB\",type=DataSource",active]
and this lead to error you see above. (

Comment: ^_^ Yei! It start to work! Thanx!!!!!!! XOXO! :)
It seems settings need some time to get to work.

Comment: How can i mark your answer as a answer to this question?

Comment: In Zabbix server configuration file, there is a parameter CacheUpdateFrequency, which tells how often to sync configuration data from the database. If it is set to a large value, that might explain why you experienced a delay before your changes were applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [question on ServerFault asked previously](https://serverfault.com/questions/582597/zabbix-jmx-jboss-monitoring), which should help in the general case of creating JMX items for Zabbix. It shows how the values in JConsole match with the arguments one has to specify in Zabbix.

In your particular case, based on the screenshot you posted, the third key in the list looks correct:

```
jmx["Catalina:class=javax.sql.DataSource,name=\"jdbc/someDB\",type=DataSource",active]
```

Zabbix documentation page, which details [item key syntax and escaping rules](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/item/key), should help getting the syntax right in the future.